# Fancybox2 modify CSS of <body> by adding margin-right

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to use fancybox2 on my website and i keep getting my page shifted to the right when i use a fancybox link (Firefox). From what i've read about it i can fix it by changing the fancybox css but i won't suceed.

I have :

```
body{
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto; !important;
}
```

And when using fancybox, it gets (seen from firebug) :

```
<body style="margin-right: 0px;">
```

I tried to change css lines:

```
.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

and

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

But it won't solve the problem.

Any help on this would be really appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use a general wrapper container instead of applying dimensions to the `body` tag? (you will save yourself many headaches ;)

Comment: You are so right. This solve my problem althought i never knew it was a bad habbit to apply some CSS on Body! Thank you i learned something and it solved my issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using !important it should go along side the value and not after the semi-colon.

This is wrong:

```
margin: auto; !important;
```

This is correct:

```
margin: auto !important;
```

Hope this gets you closer to a solution.